# Solving trigonometric integral using contour integration

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, trigonometric-integrals

How to solve this integral using contour integration:$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos px - \cos qx}{x^2} dx \stackrel{?}{=} \pi (q-p)$$

Here is what I have tried:
I don't know if I can use Residue theorem, as it has a pole of second order on the real axis, which is not simple. So I am stuck.

Comment: This problem is a good example of a not often used theorem: contour integration $\neq$ residue theorem

Comment: Note that in fact the integrand function $f$ does not have any pole. It can be extended by continuity on 0 because $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=(q^2-p^2)/2$. And by Riemann’s theorem on removable singularities, this extended function is still holomorphic on the whole complex plane. Hence the residue theorem amounts in this case to Cauchy’s theorem, i.e. to the fact that the integral of $f$ over any closed curve is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that $p, q \geq 0$, for otherwise the equality is false.

**Method 1.** Let me demonstrate a method that only relies on contour integration. Consider the contour $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{C}_{R,\epsilon}$ of the form

[image: contour]

where $\gamma_R^+$ (resp. $\gamma^-_{\epsilon}$) is the CCW-oriented (resp. CW-oriented) upper semicircular arc of radius $R$ (resp. $\epsilon$). Then by the residue theorem,

\begin{align*}
0
&= \oint_{\mathcal{C}} \frac{e^{ipz} - e^{iqz}}{z^2} \, \mathrm{d}z \\
&= \int_{L_1 \cup L_2} \frac{e^{ipx} - e^{iqx}}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\gamma^+_{R}} \frac{e^{ipz} - e^{iqz}}{z^2} \, \mathrm{d}z + \int_{\gamma^-_{\epsilon}} \frac{e^{ipz} - e^{iqz}}{z^2} \, \mathrm{d}z.
\end{align*}

The first integral becomes

$$ \int_{L_1 \cup L_2} \frac{e^{ipx} - e^{iqx}}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{L_1 \cup L_2} \frac{\cos(px) - \cos(qx)}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x, $$

which converges to the OP's integral as $R \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0^+$. For the second integral, note that

$$ \left| \int_{\gamma^+_{R}} \frac{e^{ipz} - e^{iqz}}{z^2} \, \mathrm{d}z \right|
\leq \int_{\gamma^+_{R}} \frac{|e^{ipz} - e^{iqz}|}{|z|^2} \, |\mathrm{d}z|
\leq \int_{\gamma^+_{R}} \frac{2}{R^2} \, |\mathrm{d}z|
= \frac{2\pi}{R} \to 0 $$

as $R \to \infty$. Hence the integral vanishes in the limit. Finally, noting that $e^z = 1 + z + \mathcal{O}(z^2)$ as $z \to 0$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma^-_{\epsilon}} \frac{e^{ipz} - e^{iqz}}{z^2} \, \mathrm{d}z
&= \int_{\gamma^-_{\epsilon}} \biggl( \frac{i(p-q)}{z} + \mathcal{O}(1) \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}z \\
&= -\int_{0}^{\pi} \biggl( \frac{i(p-q)}{\epsilon e^{i\theta}} + \mathcal{O}(1) \biggr) \, (i\epsilon e^{i\theta}) \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= (p-q)\pi + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon).
\end{align*}

Hence this integral converges to $(p-q)\pi$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$. Finally, combining all these computations together, we get

$$ 0 = \lim_{\substack{R \to \infty \\ \epsilon \to 0^+}} \oint_{\mathcal{C}} \frac{e^{ipz} - e^{iqz}}{z^2} \, \mathrm{d}z = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(px) - \cos(qx)}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x + (p-q)\pi, $$

proving the desired equality.

---

**Method 2.** Assuming OP is aware of the formula

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \pi \operatorname{sgn}(a), $$

which can also be proved by contour integration technique or else, we can come up with a very short proof: By integration by parts,

\begin{align*}
\require{cancel}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(px) - \cos(qx)}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \cancel{\left[ -\frac{\cos(px) - \cos(qx)}{x} \right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{p \sin(px) - q \sin (qx)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= -(p \pi \operatorname{sgn}(p) - q \pi \operatorname{sgn}(q)) \\
&= (|q| - |p|)\pi.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Residue theorem can be avoided altogether. Notice that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos px-\cos qx}{x^2}dx = \operatorname{Re}\left\{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ipx}-e^{iqx}-i(q-p)x}{x^2}dx\right\}$$

which we will denote $\int_\Bbb{R}f(z)dz$. This function has no poles and is holomorphic everywhere, therefore any closed loop line integral of this function is $0$. This gives us

$$0=\int_{[-R,R]}f(z)dz + \int_{|z|=R}f(z)dz$$

where the second integral is taken over the semicircle in the upper half plane. Since this equality is true for all values of $R$, simply take the limit as $R\to\infty $:

$$\int_\Bbb{R}f(z)dz = \lim_{R\to\infty}-\int_0^\pi\frac{e^{ipRe^{i\theta}}-e^{iqRe^{i\theta}}-i(p-q)Re^{i\theta}}{R^2e^{i2\theta}}\cdot\left(iRe^{i\theta}d\theta\right)$$

$$\longrightarrow (q-p)\int_0^\pi d\theta = \boxed{\pi(q-p)}$$

The answer is already real so there are no more simplifications to be made.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you mind additionally showing how do you solve this integral using residues? I've tried doing it myself, but I can't arrive at the solution.